# Ruby gives “No such file or directory - text.txt (Errno::ENOENT)” error

Tags: ruby

when am trying to run a ruby app ,it gives below error,

Could anyone put some light in to it .

```
ruby logger.rb
/home/swapnasa/Downloads/irclogger-master
logger.rb:14:in `read': No such file or directory - ./tmp/logger.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
        from logger.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Code goes here:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts Dir.pwd

$: << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib')

require 'irclogger'
require 'irclogger/cinch_plugin'
require 'redis'

pidfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'tmp', 'logger.pid')

begin
  old_pid = File.read(pidfile).to_i
  Process.kill 0, old_pid

  raise "An existing logger process is running with pid #{old_pid}. Refusing to start"
rescue Errno::ESRCH
end

File.open(pidfile, 'w') do |f|
  f.write Process.pid
end

bot = Cinch::Bot.new do
  configure do |c|
    c.server   = Config['server']
    c.channels = Config['channels']
    c.user     = Config['username']
    c.nick     = Config['nickname']
    c.realname = Config['realname']

    # cinch, oh god why?!
    c.plugins.plugins = [IrcLogger::CinchPlugin]
  end
end

IrcLogger::CinchPlugin.redis = Redis.new(url: Config['redis'])

bot.start
```

Comment: Seems like you are trying to open a file which doesn't exist...

Comment: might be silly ...what i did to resolve this ,i have manually created logger.pid in the tmp directory and then restarted the app and then it worked.

Comment: Found a bug on it .Now its fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be stemming from

```
pidfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'tmp', 'logger.pid')
```

Try just

```
pidfile = File.join('./tmp', 'logger.pid')
```

also add a condition in here to create the 'tmp' folder if it doesn't exist.  when you create that pid file, you can tell it to create any directories it's in.

Answer (score 0):

`pdfile = File.join( Dir::pwd,'lib', 'tmp', 'logger.pid' )`

Comment: still getting the error -/home/swapnasa/Downloads/irclogger-master
logger.rb:14:in `read': No such file or directory - /home/swapnasa/Downloads/irclogger-master/lib/tmp/logger.pid (Errno::ENOENT)
        from logger.rb:14:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the `tmp` directory doesn't exist. Try something like this:

```
piddir = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'tmp')
Dir.mkdir(piddir)
pidfile = File.join(piddir, 'logger.pid')
```

Comment: already tmp directory is present logger.rb:12:in `mkdir': File exists - ./tmp (Errno::EEXIST)
        from logger.rb:12:in `<main>'

Answer (score 0):

if you add:

```
  File.open(pidfile, 'w+') do |f|
    f.write Process.pid
  end
```

that should create the file for you automatically. Rather than you creating it first.